# CSS for Flexible but Bounded Width Padded Content Section on a Line

Tags: css

I want to make a responsive div with flexible symmetric padding and a content area that grows to a maximum width and shrinks to a minimum width described as follows:

```
 <-A-> <------------------ B -----------------> <-A->
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----+
|     |                                        |     |
|     |                                        |     |
|     |                                        |     |
|     |                                        |     |
|     |                                        |     |
|     |                                        |     |
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----+
<------------------------- W ------------------------->
```

What I want is a CSS solution that gets me:

```
A is at least 10px
B is as big as possible but no bigger than 1366px
B is no smaller than 300px
W = B + ( A * 2 ) always
```

I thought this would be a relatively straightforward thing to figure out with Google, but I am finding it surprisingly challenging to come up with a good approach. Where I'm ending up seems harder than it ought to be (a combination of media queries and calc() calls in my CSS).

Is there a simple approach / trick to doing what I'm describing, or is it just a matter of applying the right set of media queries and overriding styles to get the desired effect?

```css
.out {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.in {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1366) {
  .in {
    width: 1346px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to prevent the red area from getting smaller than 300px or greater than 1366px in width. If it gets bigger than 1366px in width I want the padding to grow symmetrically around it. I think maybe I've got it?

Comment: Your presumption is correct. You're going to have to deal with media queries here. Sorry.

Comment: It sounds like CSS Grid layout is what you want; it can definitely handle this layout and your first three conditions no sweat. You may need some augmenting to add in the W condition in your post, though. Do you have some markup and maybe some CSS already? It will be difficult to help you if we don't know what your code content looks like right now. I expect Michael_B, vals, Paulie_D, or Temani Afif to drop a solution in no time... otherwise I may take a crack at it.

Comment: By the way, for clarity, did you mean to type `W = B - ( A * 2 )`, or did you really mean `( A / 2 )`? I'm confused what that line means in plain English. I'm assuming it means you want the whole width of the line to be the width of B plus both A gutters...

Comment: Yes, OK Added html / css snippets to demonstrate my proposed solution, also corrected my formulation for W, thanks @TylerH

Comment: My proposed solution certainly does not address the min constraint on B, but if I'm going to break somewhere, that's probably the most acceptable place to break.

Comment: Both answers do a good job of handling this layout. It's a matter of what browsers you need to support (search for "grid" and for "flexbox" on https://caniuse.com/ to see browser support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your layout can be achieved using CSS Grid.

You can use [minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) to set your columns.

Example:

```css
.out {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(10px, 1fr) minmax(300px, 1366px) minmax(10px, 1fr);
}

.in {
  background: red;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, this is the simplest way to handle it; bummer on me for hitting the pub after work instead of answering this question. :-)

Comment: I'm choosing this one because it is slightly more intuitive to me, despite the slightly worse browser support metrics. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're after, I think this solution using Flexbox will do it:

```css
.out {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.in {
  background: red;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
  </div>
</div>
```

The `justify-content: center` rule will keep the `in` div centered in `out`, which gives you the symmetric padding once its width reaches 1366px. The margin on `in` being `10px` on either side means the minimum width of "A" is there as well.

Comment: A little bit more complex than the grid implementation, but flexbox does have better support across browsers. Either answer could be the best solution depending on OP's target audience.